# Jenkins and VSO integration

Tags: maven, jenkins, github

I want to pull a selenium based maven project from VSO/github in Jenkins and then execute it from another project.

I have already created a project that pulls the code from VSO. Its working fine.

But how do I execute its pom.xml from another job in jenkins.

Process will be:

2 jobs will be there in Jenkins-

JOB1-Pull the project from VSO/github(Done)

JOB2-If JOB1 succeeds then trigger JOB2 which will execute the maven project using pom.xlm which has been pulled in JOB1.(How to do it?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use pipeline plugin in jenkins: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Comment: Also this would help with building Maven https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative and pretty easy solution to this problem.

Need to follow below steps:

1. Create a Freestyle project first.
2. In General section of configuration click on Advanced button
3. Check Use Custom WorkSpace check box
4. Give a directory where you want to pull the project
5. Configure VSO/github/svn from Source Code Management
6. Save the configuration
7. Create another Freestyle project
8. Give the same directory as used in First Project for Use Custom WorkSpace
9. Invoke maven target from this project
10. In Post build action of the Project1 invoke Project2 when Project1 succeeds
11. Build Project1

Works fine for me.

Although not sure why I am not getting Use Custom WorkSpace check box for maven project.